# col-lg starting at 1500px instead of 1200px in bootstrap is it chrome displaying wrong?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap is behaving awkward, because as stated the grid system for .lg grid starts at 1200px with that min width. but my bootstrap for lg is starting at screens of 1500px wide. is it my chrome which is displaying wrong. or is my bootstrap which is failing? please see the [image](http://tinypic.com/r/kbtwjl/8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FerchoCarcho**, Try hitting your **F12** key and slide the view past 1500 and 1200 and see where things change. May be a good place to start here.

**Added...**

Add this to replace your current version of Bootstrap and see if you still have the issue.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80471/discussion-on-answer-by-angularjr-col-lg-starting-at-1500px-instead-of-1200px-in).